# Can't access network shares from a specific computer on my home network

Tags: windows, ip, lan, ping

I'm trying to connect to the Windows share on my laptop from my main PC, but the laptop doesn't respond to ping (I ping by IP, get timed out).

I can, however, ping the main PC from the laptop, and access its files.
They are both configured on the same homegroup, and have sharing enabled.

The laptop is connected via wireless, the PC is wired.  Both of them have internet access, and can access the router.

Comment: Does the laptop have security software installed?, list the OS's involved.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the laptop is configured for this service, it may not be responding to pings because it is in "stealth mode".

A program such as nmap run from a computer beside the laptop, will be able to portscan the laptop the laptop even if it is in "stealth mode".

Nmap will also confirm if the laptop is configured for what you are trying to do. Using an option like -Pn in nmap will work, even if the computer is ignoring pings.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either windows firewall is blocking all incoming connections or (if the laptop is running Vista or Windows 7), the wireless network location is "public" instead of "home" which by default will block all incoming connections. See [Choosing a network location](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Choosing-a-network-location) to see if this is the case and change it.